# Return Relationship belonging to a list Neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this dataset containing 3M nodes and more than 5M relationships. There about 8 different relationship types. Now I want to return 2 nodes if they are inter-connected.. Here the 2 nodes are A & B and I would like to see if they are inter-connected.

```
MATCH (n:WCD_Ent)
USING INDEX n:WCD_Ent(WCD_NAME)
WHERE n.WCD_NAME = "A"
MATCH (m:WCD_Ent)
USING INDEX m:WCD_Ent(WCD_NAME)
WHERE m.WCD_NAME = "B"
MATCH (n) - [r*] - (m)
RETURN n,r,m
```

This gives me Java Heap Space error.

Another conditionality I am looking to put in my query is if the relationship between the 2 nodes A&B contains one particular relationship type(NAME_MATCH) atleast once. A Could you help me address the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gabor's suggestion is the most important fix; you are blowing up heap space because you are generating a cartesian product of rows to start, then filtering out using the pattern. Generate rows using the pattern and you'll be much more space efficient. If you have an index on `WCD_Ent(WCD_NAME)`, you don't need to specify the index, either; this is something you only do if your query is running very slow and a `PROFILE` shows that the query planner is skipping the index. Try this one instead:

```
MATCH (n:WCD_Ent { WCD_NAME: "A" })-[r*..5]-(m:WCD_Ent { WCD_NAME: "B" })
WHERE ANY(rel IN r WHERE TYPE(rel) = 'NAME_MATCH')
RETURN n, r, m
```

The `WHERE` filter here will check all of the relationships in `r` (which is a collection, the way you've assigned it) and ensure that at least 1 of them matches the desired type.

Comment: Hello, I get this error. Could you help me with the same?

Type mismatch: expected Relationship but was Collection<Relationship> (line 2, column 31 (offset: 140))
"WHERE ANY(rel IN r WHERE TYPE(r) = 'NAME_MATCH')" and it points to the "r" in "Type(r)"

Comment: should be `rel`, not `r` inside the `TYPE` call. (fixed above) I can't type anything right today, sorry :)

Comment: No worries, but I still get the Java Heap Space error when I run the above query :(

Comment: try putting `EXPLAIN` at the beginning and see what kinds of estimates you get for rows? and are you sure there's actually an index on `:WCD_Ent(WCD_NAME)`?

Comment: Yes, there is an index on WCD_NAME. Also I get this estimate - Filter m.WCD_NAME == { AUTOSTRING1 } AND m:WCD_Ent and any{rel in r where RelationshipTypeFunction{rel} == {AUTOSTRING2}) as 0 estimated rows

Comment: Maybe consider adding a top bound (or at least a direction) to that relationship, it's probably catching far far more paths than you think it should.

Comment: Adding a direction to that relationship did not work either

Comment: Try the top bound, then. `[r*..5]`. Your current query could theoretically touch your entire graph, you have to restrict it somehow if you don't want it to blow up.

Comment: Another thing to note...your match with r* will search for ALL paths regardless of direction and relationship type, basically crawling your entire graph to find all possible matches, probably the main source of your slowdown. Adding an upper bound is a good move, but you may also want to consider limiting the number of paths matched, either by using shortestPath() in your match, or by adding a LIMIT 1 on your return.

Answer (score 1):

Tore's answer (including the variable relationship upper bound) is the best one for finding whether two nodes are connected and if a certain relationship exists in a path connecting them.

One weakness with most of the solutions given so far is that there is no limitation on the variable relationship match, meaning the query is going to crawl your entire graph attempting to match on all possible paths, instead of only checking that one such path exists and then stopping. This is likely the cause of your heap space error.

Tore's suggesting on adding an upper bound on the variable length relationships in your match is a great solution, as it also helps out in cases where the two nodes aren't connected, preventing you from having to crawl the entire graph. In all cases, the upper bound should prevent the heap from blowing up.

Here are a couple more possibilities. I'm leaving off the relationship upper bound, but that can easily be added in if needed.

```
// this one won't check for the particular relationship type in the path
// but doesn't need to match on all possible paths, just find connectedness
MATCH (n:WCD_Ent { WCD_NAME: "A" }), (m:WCD_Ent { WCD_NAME: "B" })
RETURN EXISTS((n)-[*]-(m))

// using shortestPath() will only give you a single path back that works
// however WHERE ANY may be a filter to apply after matches are found
// so this may still blow up, not sure
MATCH (n:WCD_Ent { WCD_NAME: "A" }), (m:WCD_Ent { WCD_NAME: "B" })
RETURN shortestPath((n)-[r*]-(m))
WHERE ANY(rel IN r WHERE TYPE(rel) = 'NAME_MATCH')

// Adding LIMIT 1 will only return one path result
// Unsure if this will prevent the heap from blowing up though
// The performance and outcome may be identical to the above query
MATCH (n:WCD_Ent { WCD_NAME: "A" }), (m:WCD_Ent { WCD_NAME: "B" })
MATCH (n)-[r*]-(m)
WHERE ANY(rel IN r WHERE TYPE(rel) = 'NAME_MATCH')
RETURN n, r, m
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Some enhancements:

1. Instead of the `WHERE` condition, you can bind the property value inside the pattern.
2. You can combine the three `MATCH` conditions into a single one, which makes sure that the query engine will not calculate a Cartesian product of `n` AND `m`. (You can also use `EXPLAIN` to visualize the query plan and check this.)

The resulting query:

```
MATCH (n:WCD_Ent { WCD_NAME: "A" })-[r*]-(m:WCD_Ent { WCD_NAME: "B" })
RETURN n, r, m
```

*Update: Tore Eschliman pointed out that you don't need to specify the indices, so I removed these two lines from the query:*

```
USING INDEX n:WCD_Ent(WCD_NAME)
USING INDEX m:WCD_Ent(WCD_NAME)
```

Comment: Also, on using "EXPLAIN", there was no output. Hence, could not visualize the query plan